# Link excel cell to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to link cells to another sheet, not just copy cell values
The code below is an attempt but tries to show what I need

```
For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Cells(Row, col).Formula = sheet.Cells(4, 5).Address
Next
```

Can someone help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You must use sheet name and sign `=` like this:

```
Cells(Row, col).Formula = _
  "='" & sheet.Name & "'!" & sheet.Cells(4, 5).Address( _
    RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

Comment: `sheet.Name` should be surrounded by simple quotes in case it contains spaces

Comment: fix: sheet.Name should be surrounded by simple quotes